# Java vararg Object... with mixed data types

Tags: java

how to extract values from a mixed type Object... vararg in Java?

For example

Object... args is passed an int, a string and a Date like below

```
Hello(5, "Hello", Date.now);

Hello(Object... args) {...}
```

Comment: There's no type safe way to do this with an `Object...`. Cast each individual element of the array to the type you expect. The correct solution is (likely) to not use `Object...` at all, but a POJO holder type.

Comment: Your `Hello` should be rewritten.

Comment: You should probably redesign and rethink at this point. Maybe you find a common interface, or create one. Anything more specific than `Object` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend doing this, but since you asked:

```
public void Hello(Object... args) {
    ...
}
```

`args.length` is the number of arguments passed.

`args[0]` is the first argument passed. And so on through `args[args.length - 1]`. They will each be an `Object` until you cast them.

The problem with doing this in real life is that the future developer writing code to call your method is almost guaranteed to make a mistake. You've provided no type safety or any mechanism to make sure they can't call the method incorrectly. Further explained [here](http://www.grahamlea.com/2013/08/murphys-law-every-line-of-code/).

Comment: Well, after editing your answer it might be acceptable.

Comment: I think OP asked how to retrieve the classes of the specific elements, not only the values. Or maybe both. Maybe up to the point that he can use them again like before, with full type information (so including a cast).